# ember adapter pass id

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I want to be able to pass an id to rest point while using ember data. My end-point looks like v3/enterprise/inventory/items/{id}/links. I want to inject the id while making the request such as this.store.findAll('each-item-links', { id: itemId }). However, it does not work. I extended the Ember REST adapter and override the namespace but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to request a single record through Ember Data, then you want to use `findRecord` instead of `findAll`.

Also, if you need control over how the URL is built (what you have there looks like it might not map to the `RESTAdapter` too cleanly) you can override the `_buildURL` method to change the URL that the request is sent to. It is given the ID from `findRecord` so you can generate the URL whatever you want. Technically this is "private API" but I wouldn't worry too much about overwriting that.

**Edit:** To avoid using private API, there is also [a public `buildURL` method](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/buildURL?anchor=buildURL) that can be used instead.

Comment: They didn't mention anything regarding buidURL is private or public. I am confused is it private or not?. https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/buildURL?anchor=buildURL

Comment: Huh, I guess it isn't private anymore. I might have been looking at the docs for a slightly older version of Ember Data that used `_buildURL` instead; the fact that it's public is all the more reason to use that to customize your URL.

Comment: But docs didn't mention it as `public` like the way they do for other methods.

Comment: The docs show public methods by default. There's a checkbox you can mark to see private API as well; if you do so, you can see that the `_buildRL` method is in there (what I originally suggested)`. `buildURL` is public.